# Why setting autocompleteSearchBox componentRestrictions country object google map does not change its locations?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In my Laravel 8 / Alpinejs 2.8 app
I use google map and when I open form with existing data I show selected country with
setting autocompleteSearchBox componentRestrictions.country and it works OK.
But if user selects other country I try to change country in map and failed.
My code:

```
function adminAdLocationEditorComponentSetup() {
    console.log('adminAdLocationEditorComponentSetup::')

    return {

        autocompleteSearchBox: null, // google map instances
        geocoder: null,
        map: null,
        ...
    },


    initialize: function (isInsert, adLocationLat, adLocationLng) {
        let form_ad_location_edit = document.querySelector("#form_ad_location_edit")
        adLocationLng = parseFloat(adLocationLng)
        adLocationLat = parseFloat(adLocationLat)
        console.log('adLocationLng::')
        console.log(adLocationLng)

        if (isEmpty(adLocationLat) || isEmpty(adLocationLng)) {
            console.log('INSIDE!!::')
            adLocationLat = 51.5000
            adLocationLng = -0.1100
        }
        console.log('adLocationLat::')
        console.log(adLocationLat)
        form_ad_location_edit.addEventListener("keyup keypress", function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if (keyCode === 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });


        this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

        const fieldKey = 'ad_location';
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(fieldKey + '-map'), {
            center: {lat: adLocationLat, lng: adLocationLng}, // create map with default values
            zoom: 13
        });
        let self = this
        this.map.addListener('click', function (event) {
            self.setAdLocationCoordinatesPoint(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng(), true)
        });

        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: this.map,
            position: {lat: adLocationLat, lng: adLocationLng},
        });

        let country = document.querySelector("#country").value
        if (country) {
            options.componentRestrictions.country = country
        }
        this.autocompleteSearchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
        this.autocompleteSearchBox.key = fieldKey
        google.maps.event.addListener(self.autocompleteSearchBox, 'place_changed', function () {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        ...
        });
        // }
    }

    setAdLocationCoordinatesPoint: function (lat, lng, showPopupAlert) {
        document.querySelector("#lat").value = lat
        document.querySelector("#lng").value = lng
    }


    countrySelected: function (option) { // ewhen country is selected
        document.querySelector("#country").value = option.value
        document.querySelector("#country_label").value = option.label
        this.autocompleteSearchBox.componentRestrictions.country = option.value // I set new country
        console.log('this.autocompleteSearchBox::')
        console.log(this.autocompleteSearchBox)
    }
, 
}
} // function adminAdLocationEditorComponentSetup() {
```

In the console I see valid autocompleteSearchBox.componentRestrictions object
with new country set, but google map has not changed it country : https://prnt.sc/113pkxm
I did not find any update/apply method for google map and as this.autocompleteSearchBox is global
object I expected it will work correctly.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documented `Autocomplete` `componentRestrictions` property.

Where you use it initially is in the [`AutocompleteOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions) anonymous object that is used in the [`Autocomplete`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#Autocomplete.constructor) constructor.

Use the documented [`setComponentRestrictions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#Autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions) function on the [`Autocomplete`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#Autocomplete) class.

Change:

```
    countrySelected: function (option) { // ewhen country is selected
        document.querySelector("#country").value = option.value
        document.querySelector("#country_label").value = option.label
        this.autocompleteSearchBox.componentRestrictions.country = option.value // I set new country
        console.log('this.autocompleteSearchBox::')
        console.log(this.autocompleteSearchBox)
    }
```

To:

```
    countrySelected: function (option) { // ewhen country is selected
        document.querySelector("#country").value = option.value
        document.querySelector("#country_label").value = option.label
        this.autocompleteSearchBox.setComponentRestrictions({country:option.value}); // set new country
        console.log('this.autocompleteSearchBox::')
        console.log(this.autocompleteSearchBox)
    }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/pkj2cn3s/)
[image: screenshot with US selected]
[image: screenshot with BE selected]
[image: screenshot with FR selected]

Comment: I replaced code autocompleteSearchBox.componentRestriction with line this.autocompleteSearchBox.setComponentRestrictions({country:option.value}); , but it did not have any effect. Location was not changed

Comment: Works for me in this [proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/pkj2cn3s/).  I'm not sure how you are testing it or what you mean by "Location was not changed".